# Exam class auto complete in TexStudio

Tags: auto-completion

I am using TexStudio and exam class. It runs fine and produces the output I want but I cannot get TexStudio to recognise the commands from the exam class and hence auto complete.

Comment: Please provide the Minimal Working Example.

Comment: When I type \begin{parts} or \question, the auto complete does not include these commands.

Comment: See: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion]